# TYPO3 extend flexform find not file

Tags: typo3-8.x, flexform

I would like to expand an extension while changing the flexform. However, I cannot get access to my Flexform.

```
call_user_func(

    function($extKey) {

 $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist']['test_pi1'] = 'pi_flexform';

 \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue('test_pi1','FILE:EXT:test2/Configuration/FlexForm/test.xml');

})
```

What's wrong with it?

The file is not flawed because I changed a text entry to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

what is the correct $_EXTKEY for your extension? Try

`$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $_EXTKEY) . '_pi1';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForm/test.xml');`

Comment: `$_EXTKEY` should/could not be used any longer. TYPO3 caches those configuration files, where you might use this variable, the caching includes concatenation of all similar files from all extensions. so there is no extension variable available any longer (except for those files which are inlcuded individualiy). TLDR: don't use variable `$_EXTKEY` in files where this code belongs (`configuration/...`)

Comment: I changed it to "test_pi1" because I want to change the flexform of the test extension. It does not work.

Comment: I have adopted the Flexform integration from the extension I want to extend. Does not work.

Comment: Ok, you must override the flexform like the felogin extension in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content,php.

Comment: Again my FlexForm is not taken over.

Comment: When I take the integration of the Flexform out of the other extension, my Flexform takes effect. Is there something wrong with the order here?

Comment: Have you tried to declare a dependency to the other extension in the ext_emconf.php and composer.json of your extension? This regulates in many cases the loading order e.g. in the PackageStates-File.

Comment: PackageStates file was it with the order. I thank you.